# Gfortran does not have module Funits while ifort does

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Once O tried to compile Fortran code that relies on `funits`. while it is not available in gfortran 4.9.3.

```
  use FUNITS
      1
  Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'funits.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

here is gfortran information

```
gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.9.3/work/gcc-4.9.3/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/python --enable-languages=c,c++,java,fortran --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4' --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --disable-altivec --disable-fixed-point --enable-targets=all --enable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libcilkrts --enable-vtable-verify --enable-libvtv --enable-lto --without-cloog --enable-libsanitizer
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Gentoo 4.9.3 p1.5, pie-0.6.4)
```

Instead ifort version 14.0.3 has it pre-installed.

How can I install `funits` with gfortran as we need to rely on the free software?

Comment: Be sure to use tag [tag:fortran], not too many people follof [tag:gfortran].

Answer (score 3):

FUNITS is a module. There is no such module in standard Fortran. It must be some external library, not an intrinsic module.

It is also not part of Intel Fortran although you claim it to be. It is not part of my Intel Fortran installation and it is not mentioned anywhere in the manual.

You have to find where does it come from, who supplies this library and compile it for gfortran yourself.

Or find out what it does and implement that functionality yourself.

A simple web search found 2 modules called `FUNITS` on the internet. Both just declare some file unit number constants. I have no idea whether you need one of them or not https://mfix.netl.doe.gov/develop/STI/source_profile_2015-2/mfix_und/MFIX_html/9899.html  http://home.chpc.utah.edu/~u0703457/STILT_tutorial/WRF_STILT_code/STILT_updated/funits.f  Probably it will be better to search your hard drive.